# how to restrict FTP using htaccess file, want to allow only some ips

Tags: ftp

i want to allow some IP using htaccess file for my FTP access

any one know how to do that ???

Answer (score 1):

From http://home.golden.net/htaccess.html

`AuthType Basic

<Limit GET POST>

order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from 199.166.210.

allow from .golden.net

allow from proxy.aol.com

allow from fish.wiretap.net

</Limit>`